# Why Epoch didn't fail using java.util.date?

Tags: java, date, timestamp, epoch

In the following code I am converting a java.util.date into java.sql.date. I am confused at a point that while giving the date before epoch like given below and I have also used date.getTime() method which gives miliseconds from the epoch, it gave me the right time as shown in the results. My questions is why it didn't fail(as I assumed it should)? Why It gave the right time?

**Code:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); //defining format
String dateOfAdmissionInString = "22-01-1966 05:03:33"; 
Date utilDateOfAdmission = sdf2.parse(dateOfAdmissionInString); 
java.sql.Timestamp sqlDateOfAdmission = new Java.sql.Timestamp(utilDateOfAdmission.getTime()); 
 System.out.println("utilDateOfAdmission:" + utilDateOfAdmission);
 System.out.println("sqlDateOfAdmission:" + sqlDateOfAdmission);
```

**Result:**

```
utilDateOfAdmission: Sat Jan 22 05:03:33 PKT 1966

sqlDateOfAdmission: 1966-01-22 05:03:33.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My questions is why it didn't fail

Because the number of milliseconds since The Epoch is allowed to be negative, which indicates date/times *before* Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT.

[Gratuitous example](http://ideone.com/ZxsZCb): Elvis' birthdate:

```
Date dt = new Date(-1103932800000L);
System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

Comment: Alright! So is it okay to use this approach? or will it break at some point?

Comment: @RabiaNazkhan: It's entirely fine. Note that for anything significant, you want to use `java.util.Calendar` (which also uses offsets from The Epoch) or the various [`java.time` classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (or JodaTime) instead, as `Date` has very few useful features, something like 90% of its API is deprecated. But negative offsets from The Epoch are perfectly normal. For instance, `java.util.GregorianCalendar` handles the discontinuity in October 1582, so clearly expects to handle negative epoch values.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much Sir for clearing my concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The epoch just specifies where the value ZERO is.  Dates/times before that point can still be represented as negative offsets from the epoch.

Comment: I didn't get you Sir.

Comment: A time value of -86,400,000 is 1 day prior to the epoch, or December 31, 1969 at 00:00:00 (in GMT/UTC zone)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer.